# Tobit model with corner solution and selection problem

Tags: regression, econometrics, censoring, tobit-regression

How would you estimate a model with a log transformed dependent variable  with a corner at zero and a continuous distribution for strictly positive values AND an additional selection problem due to missings?

**Background**:

Dependent variable y (expenditures)  where y>=0 with "true" 0 values
(y is always observed. The value zero is not arbitrary; it is observed data).

Thus I have a corner at zero and a continuous  distribution for strictly positive values.
The distribution is such that I prefer to  make a log transformation of the dependent variable y  (ln y)

Given such situation  I would normally  start with a tobit model.
Based on that I would estimate several two part models ( according to Wooldridge)

1.Cragg Truncated Normal Hurdle Model
 
2. Lognormal Hurdle Model
3.Exponential Type II Tobit Model

Finally, in order to compare these two part models  I would use the value of the log-likelihood function..

**But** what happens if I have additionally a true missing data problem. 
That is,  the value  zero is observed data but additionally I have missings in y (selection problem)
After taking logs I could not distinguish between the true zeros ( corner solution)  and the missings due to the selection problem.
 
Do you know any reference on this issue?

Comment: Why are they missing? Are you thinking of a situation like you might have with annual expenditures on major consumer durables (like a washing machine)? You have people who would never buy (your corner solution types) and those who would have a *desired* expenditure above zero, but there's no option that is cheap enough for them, so their *actual* expenditure is also zero. You want to separate these two types?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I think of something like firms' R&D expenditures. In a survey some firms report to spend >=0, some firms report to spend zero and the third group just does not answer the question.